# How to get pre formatted text preserving newlines using selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to grab all the text inside a `pre` tag using Selenium Chrome driver in Python.
Let's consider this Hacker Earth Submission [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/key/3b75fc6f8009460fb4e2f0db3c2cf58c/).

Whenever I try to get the text `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('pre').text` , It removes the newlines. How do I grab the text preserving all the newlines?

I am getting the following output

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    #define gc getchar
    #define pc putchar
#else
    #define gc getchar_unlocked
    #define pc putchar_unlocked
#endif
 using namespace std;
 #define vi vector<int>
#define si set<int>
#define vs vector<string>
#define pii pair<int,int>
#define vpi vector<pii>
#define pri priority_queue<int>
#define rev_pri priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> >
#define mpi map<int,int>
#define i64 long long int
#define endl '\n'
#define pi acos(-1)
#define all(v) v.begin(),v.end()
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define mod 1000000007
#define inf INT_MAX/2
#define infll LLONG_MAX/3
#define For(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define Fre(i,a,b) for(int i = a; i < b; i++)
#define sf(n) scanf("%d", &n)
#define sff(a,b) scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)
#define sfff(a,b,c) scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)
#define pfn(n) printf("%d\n", n)
#define pfs(n) printf("%d ", n)
#define eps 1e-8
#define ff first
#define ss second
#define mem(a,b) memset(a,b,sizeof(a))
#define READ freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin)
#define WRITE freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout)
#define sz size()
#define dbg(i) printf("yo %d\n", i)
#define foreach(i,c) for(__typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
#define sqr(a) (a) * (a)
#define clr clear()
#define CASE(a) printf("Case %d: ",a)
 //int dx[] = {0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1};
//int dy[] = {1,0,-1,0,1,-1,-1,1};
  //i64 gcd(i64 a,i64 b){if(!b)return a;return gcd(b,a%b);}
 //inline void fastRead(int *a){register char c=0;while(c<33)c=gc();*a=0;while(c>33){*a=*a*10+c-'0';c=gc();}}
 //inline void fastWrite(int a){char snum[20];int i=0;do{snum[i++]=a%10+48;a=a/10;}while(a!=0);i=i-1;while(i>=0)pc(snum[i--]);pc('\n');}
 //i64 bigmod(i64 num,i64 n){if(n==0)return 1;i64 x=bigmod(num,n/2);x=x*x%mod;if(n%2==1)x=x*num%mod;return x;}
 //i64 modinverse(i64 num){return bigmod(num,mod-2)%mod;}
 //i64 po(i64 a,i64 b){i64 ans=1;while(b--)ans *= a;return ans;}
 //i64 ncr(i64 n,i64 r){if(n==r)return 1;if(r==1)return n;if(dp[n][r]!=-1)return dp[n][r];return dp[n][r]=ncr(n-1,r)+ncr(n-1,r-1);}
  // bit manipulations
 //bool checkbit(int mask,int bit){return mask & (1<<bit);}
 //int setbit(int mask,int bit){ return mask  (1<<bit) ; }
 //int clearbit(int mask,int bit){return mask & ~(1<<bit);}
 //int togglebit(int mask,int bit){return mask ^ (1<<bit);}
   int main()
{
         i64 t,n,k;
        cin >> t;
        while(t--) {
                cin >> n >> k;
                i64 ans = 0;
                while(n >= k) {
                        ans += n/k;
                        n = n / k + n % k;
                }
                 cout << ans << endl;
        }
                    return 0;
}
```

But I want the following output

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    #define gc getchar
    #define pc putchar
#else
    #define gc getchar_unlocked
    #define pc putchar_unlocked
#endif

using namespace std;

#define vi vector<int>
#define si set<int>
#define vs vector<string>
#define pii pair<int,int>
#define vpi vector<pii>
#define pri priority_queue<int>
#define rev_pri priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> >
#define mpi map<int,int>
#define i64 long long int
#define endl '\n'
#define pi acos(-1)
#define all(v) v.begin(),v.end()
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define mod 1000000007
#define inf INT_MAX/2
#define infll LLONG_MAX/3
#define For(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define Fre(i,a,b) for(int i = a; i < b; i++)
#define sf(n) scanf("%d", &n)
#define sff(a,b) scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)
#define sfff(a,b,c) scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)
#define pfn(n) printf("%d\n", n)
#define pfs(n) printf("%d ", n)
#define eps 1e-8
#define ff first
#define ss second
#define mem(a,b) memset(a,b,sizeof(a))
#define READ freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin)
#define WRITE freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout)
#define sz size()
#define dbg(i) printf("yo %d\n", i)
#define foreach(i,c) for(__typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
#define sqr(a) (a) * (a)
#define clr clear()
#define CASE(a) printf("Case %d: ",a)

//int dx[] = {0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1};
//int dy[] = {1,0,-1,0,1,-1,-1,1};


//i64 gcd(i64 a,i64 b){if(!b)return a;return gcd(b,a%b);}

//inline void fastRead(int *a){register char c=0;while(c<33)c=gc();*a=0;while(c>33){*a=*a*10+c-'0';c=gc();}}

//inline void fastWrite(int a){char snum[20];int i=0;do{snum[i++]=a%10+48;a=a/10;}while(a!=0);i=i-1;while(i>=0)pc(snum[i--]);pc('\n');}

//i64 bigmod(i64 num,i64 n){if(n==0)return 1;i64 x=bigmod(num,n/2);x=x*x%mod;if(n%2==1)x=x*num%mod;return x;}

//i64 modinverse(i64 num){return bigmod(num,mod-2)%mod;}

//i64 po(i64 a,i64 b){i64 ans=1;while(b--)ans *= a;return ans;}

//i64 ncr(i64 n,i64 r){if(n==r)return 1;if(r==1)return n;if(dp[n][r]!=-1)return dp[n][r];return dp[n][r]=ncr(n-1,r)+ncr(n-1,r-1);}


// bit manipulations

//bool checkbit(int mask,int bit){return mask & (1<<bit);}

//int setbit(int mask,int bit){ return mask  (1<<bit) ; }

//int clearbit(int mask,int bit){return mask & ~(1<<bit);}

//int togglebit(int mask,int bit){return mask ^ (1<<bit);}



int main()
{

        i64 t,n,k;
        cin >> t;
        while(t--) {
                cin >> n >> k;
                i64 ans = 0;
                while(n >= k) {
                        ans += n/k;
                        n = n / k + n % k;
                }

                cout << ans << endl;
        }












        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this. It might help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/key/3b75fc6f8009460fb4e2f0db3c2cf58c/");

table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li")
print len(table_rows)
for rows in table_rows:
    print rows.text

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```cpp
111
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    #define gc getchar
    #define pc putchar
#else
    #define gc getchar_unlocked
    #define pc putchar_unlocked
#endif

using namespace std;

#define vi vector<int>
#define si set<int>
#define vs vector<string>
#define pii pair<int,int>
#define vpi vector<pii>
#define pri priority_queue<int>
#define rev_pri priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> >
#define mpi map<int,int>
#define i64 long long int
#define endl '\n'
#define pi acos(-1)
#define all(v) v.begin(),v.end()
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define mod 1000000007
#define inf INT_MAX/2
#define infll LLONG_MAX/3
#define For(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define Fre(i,a,b) for(int i = a; i < b; i++)
#define sf(n) scanf("%d", &n)
#define sff(a,b) scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)
#define sfff(a,b,c) scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)
#define pfn(n) printf("%d\n", n)
#define pfs(n) printf("%d ", n)
#define eps 1e-8
#define ff first
#define ss second
#define mem(a,b) memset(a,b,sizeof(a))
#define READ freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin)
#define WRITE freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout)
#define sz size()
#define dbg(i) printf("yo %d\n", i)
#define foreach(i,c) for(__typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
#define sqr(a) (a) * (a)
#define clr clear()
#define CASE(a) printf("Case %d: ",a)

//int dx[] = {0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1};
//int dy[] = {1,0,-1,0,1,-1,-1,1};


//i64 gcd(i64 a,i64 b){if(!b)return a;return gcd(b,a%b);}

//inline void fastRead(int *a){register char c=0;while(c<33)c=gc();*a=0;while(c>33){*a=*a*10+c-'0';c=gc();}}

//inline void fastWrite(int a){char snum[20];int i=0;do{snum[i++]=a%10+48;a=a/10;}while(a!=0);i=i-1;while(i>=0)pc(snum[i--]);pc('\n');}

//i64 bigmod(i64 num,i64 n){if(n==0)return 1;i64 x=bigmod(num,n/2);x=x*x%mod;if(n%2==1)x=x*num%mod;return x;}

//i64 modinverse(i64 num){return bigmod(num,mod-2)%mod;}

//i64 po(i64 a,i64 b){i64 ans=1;while(b--)ans *= a;return ans;}

//i64 ncr(i64 n,i64 r){if(n==r)return 1;if(r==1)return n;if(dp[n][r]!=-1)return dp[n][r];return dp[n][r]=ncr(n-1,r)+ncr(n-1,r-1);}


// bit manipulations

//bool checkbit(int mask,int bit){return mask & (1<<bit);}

//int setbit(int mask,int bit){ return mask  (1<<bit) ; }

//int clearbit(int mask,int bit){return mask & ~(1<<bit);}

//int togglebit(int mask,int bit){return mask ^ (1<<bit);}



int main()
{

        i64 t,n,k;
        cin >> t;
        while(t--) {
                cin >> n >> k;
                i64 ans = 0;
                while(n >= k) {
                        ans += n/k;
                        n = n / k + n % k;
                }

                cout << ans << endl;
        }












        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am actually getting this exact output. The empty lines are being removed. I want the keep the empty lines and proper formatting. Updated the question with the output format I want.

Comment: @NjRafi I have update my code for requirement. Please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I've been looking for.